# How to narrow object type based on field presence?

Tags: typescript, type-inference, narrowing

I have 2 similar endpoints, that's one for getting a list, the other for getting a filtered list. Now it's not possible to merge them into one endpoint with query parameters on backend. So I have a function that decides which endpoint to use based on presence of id field. The problem is that I cannot get correct type inference, `args` couldn't be narrowed.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?importHelpers=true&module=1&keyofStringsOnly=false#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-LIdEqFSAA)

How to do it? Maybe, it's better to use union, I see no discriminant field, though?

```
export interface Arguments {
    id?: number;
    token?: string;
    pageSize: number;
}
    
function requestTo1stEndpoint(a: {
    id: number;
    token?: string;
    pageSize: number;
}) {
    return Promise.resolve(1);
}

function requestTo2ndEndpoint(a: {
    token?: string;
    pageSize: number;
}) {
    return Promise.resolve(2);
}
    
async function request(args: Arguments) {
    let fun: typeof requestTo1stEndpoint | typeof requestTo2ndEndpoint
    if (args.id !== undefined) {
        fun = requestTo1stEndpoint
    } else
        fun = requestTo2ndEndpoint
        
    const response = await fun(args)
}
```

[This](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?importHelpers=true&module=1&keyofStringsOnly=false#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-Ki8X4XBoNAwZBCPjU1rKv2Bticpzcl6ohHzClLAIIdZhDAOq2VfLmDX9ToJh7Q5NgHlpxHkxYIXyrdi5zb5y3W4VsfDJjlV2FERG4ZW4LXzAXV2vlm5AA) doesn't work either:

```
async function request(args: Arguments) {
    let responsePromise: Response

    // this doesn't work either
    // if ('id' in args) 
    if (args.id !== undefined) {
        // cannot be narrowed
        responsePromise = requestTo1stEndpoint(args)
    } else
        responsePromise = requestTo2ndEndpoint(args)

    const response = await responsePromise
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a [User Defined Type Guard and "in" Narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-in-operator-narrowing).

To make this work, we also *need* to have the code that depends on the type of `args` *inside* the `true` or `false` of the `if` that uses the type guard. This is because the compiler "knows" it is `Type1` if the `true` portion executes and it is not `Type1` in the else.

```
interface Type1{
    id: number;
    token?: string;
    pageSize: number;
}

interface Type2 {
    token?: string;
    pageSize: number;
}

function isType1(x: Type1 | Type2): x is Type1 {
    if ('id' in x) return true;
    return false;
}

function requestTo1stEndpoint(a: Type1) {
    return Promise.resolve(1);
}

function requestTo2ndEndpoint(a: Type2) {
    return Promise.resolve(2);
}

async function request(args: Type1 | Type2) {
    const response = isType1(args) ? await requestTo1stEndpoint(args) : await requestTo2ndEndpoint(args);
}
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoE8AOECMBvAWAChlTlgATALmRAFcBbAI2gG5izkwB7AawhAB+GgGcwUUAHN2JMpjiSIAZWAAvCDXrM2xAL7FioSLEQoM2AEzJCs0j35DR4qTM7zFK9ZsYsoM-UTEMHQgCGDA3CDkIua4ABQAHjSxOMgAPmhYEBYAlDQJ0ZnYqTacwDDIcQDklFXkUQk5yFAQYHRQUeJ0EK5kLW0dyPAANiI9egZEwaHhkc0QAI7dYqjcOGIAoiAUmNxGcXDJWThNpX2t7VEAClDcDMBjAHQtItzDAG4QcSf+k9NhESiLSWEBW3As2y2Oz24AOR0spw45wG11u9yeLzenziuV+gSIcBE6FCQxCALmwOWYAOUEkInhuHSRWyiNsyAQkTE8xEuxAY2QAF5oikaXSmoJkHAAO5wYBgeYgsHrMBQ3b7OC0kRNGjS2XyymgsCrCEUVUw6kasX+IA)

Comment: Thank you! I knew about type guards with predicate, but for some reason I thought in this case it's possible to do without them

Comment: You *can* do it without, but that would require "casting" or essentially telling TypeScript "I know better than you", which usually ends up looking messier in my opinion.

Comment: Agree, I don't like casting, as it's not safe